# ELF binary make section unaccessible

Tags: elf

I'm implementing a prototype stack protection mechanism for a university assignment. 
The test binary that I'm trying to "harden" is a statically linked elf binary that has multiple stacks, which are hard coded as elf sections. The different stacks are seperated by guard pages (4096 byte sections). 
The guard pages should be unaccesible, similar to what mprotect's PROT_NONE would do. I've tried using objcopy with --set-section-flags on readonly but overflowing one of the stacks still results in data being written to the guard page, which means it's clearly still writeable.

How can I make a section like this unaccesible using only elf section flags (or a similar elf property)?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've been able to find is using an ELF LOAD program header with FLAGS set to 0.

See the "reserve" PHDR in the Chromium NACL linker script: https://src.chromium.org/native_client/trunk/src/native_client/src/trusted/service_runtime/linux/nacl_bootstrap.x